# Continue Processing Bash Script After LFTP

Tags: bash, lftp

I'd like to use lftp in the beginning of a bash script, but how do I exit lftp without stopping the script from processing? I've tried ending the lftp part with "exit", "quit", and "bye", but they all stop the script.

Previously, I split into two scripts and cron'ed them to run in the right order. Is it possible to combine them into one script?

Comment: FYI, since you've solved your problem, you can post your solution as an answer. :-)

Comment: Don't post your solution in the answer, instead add an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or more explicitly, use << EOF.

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
#CMP 01.04.2013
#
#<<EOF below is the functional equivalent of hitting .Enter. on your keyboard.
#It allows the rest of the commands to be executed once connected

lftp -e 'mirror -R /home/pi/LocalDirToMirror ~/TargetDir' -u YourUsername,YourPassword  ftp://FTP_URL_Location <<EOF
quit 0
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

End the LFTP part of the script with EOF, on its own line. That's all you need to do!